# how to insert records on account and contact

Tags: data-loader

Can you please suggest how to deploy records to both object Account and contact at a time using data loader.i know using some relationship we can do but practically don't have any idea please help to achieve this

Answer (score 5):

Following things to be noted.

1. The term `deploy` is used when we deploy configuration and customization components, which is nothing but metadata. We use word `migration` when data to be loaded into Salesforce.
2. Dataloader supports migration of data one object at a time. So you need to insert Account records first and then you can insert Contacts based on AccountId.
3. You can also use `Import Wizard`, if you want to load less than 50000 records.

Refer [When to Use Data Loader](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=when_to_use_the_data_loader.htm&type=5)

4. To load Account and Contact same time, you need to use `ExternalId` which will help to build relationship between Account and Contact, and then write code to insert those records.

Refer my post [Insert Multiple Parent and Child Records with External Id](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/insert-multiple-parent-and-child.html) where you can find insertion of multiple Account and Contact records in a single statement.

5. Including comments from [Mark Pond](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/660/mark-pond): You can load accounts and contacts simultaneously using the composite functionality of the REST API.
   Refer [Create Nested Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm)

Comment: Also not dataloader driven, but worth a mention - you can load accounts and contacts simultaneously using the composite functionality of the REST API. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_composite_sobject_tree_create.htm

Comment: @saritha If my ans solves your purpose then accept this so that others may find this useful